# Should I use parentheses in declarative macros?

Tags: rust, syntax, macros, operator-precedence, parentheses

Should I add parentheses to macro rules, as in my below macro I added parentheses around `$addr` for the case if `$addr`'s top-level operation is a low precedence operator (lower than `+`)?

```rust
/// `read_field!(memory, address, C::f)`
macro_rules! read_field {
    ($mem:expr,$addr:expr,$ty:ident::$field:ident) => {
        $mem.return_value(($addr) + offset_of!($ty::$field).as_u32() as usize)
    };
    ($mem:expr,$addr:expr,<$ty:path>::$field:ident) => {
        $mem.return_value(($addr) + offset_of!(<$ty:path>::$field).as_u32() as usize)
    };
}
```

Will these extra parentheses lead to unwanted compiler warnings and how to eliminate such warnings?

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to use the parentheses; Rust automatically prevents this from being a problem.

- When you match input tokens as `:expr`, the expression is automatically treated as an indivisible unit, as if it had “invisible parentheses” around it; this means that the input expression (`$addr` in your example) cannot be broken up by a higher-precedence operator next to it, nor can they be parsed further by another macro.
- When a macro is *called* (i.e. `read_field!(...)`), the call cannot just appear in an arbitrary location in the source code and be expanded; it has to appear in a specific context such as where an expression is expected, and when it does, it will be required to expand to a single expression — not tokens that will be interpreted as different parts of the surrounding expression.

Demonstration of using a higher-precedence operator outside the macro call, and a lower-precedence one in the arguments:

```rust
macro_rules! incm {
    ($x:expr) => { 1 + $x }
}
fn incf(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 1
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(incm!(3) * 100, incf(3) * 100);
    assert_eq!(incm!(1 & 2), incf(1 & 2));
}
```

With regard to precedence, the macro is as “safe” as an ordinary function call.

Comment: If you look at the generated code from `cargo expand`, it actually has added parentheses to make sure that it behaves correctly. I was surprised by that - I was expecting this to be one of those edge cases where the generated code behaves differently from the macro call itself.]

Comment: Using `cargo expand`, `incm!(3) * 10` => `(1 + 3) * 10`, but  `incm!(3) + 10` => `1 + 3 + 10`. Which I find surprising!